# How to stop redelivery of message back to service bus queue when message lock times out

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, exceptionhandler

I want to stop redelivery of message back to service bus queue only when it times out , currently I am using processmessageasync to read the message and processerrorasync to handler the errors

Do not want to use dead letter as soon as it times out I want to remove the message from my queue and not retry

Answer (score 1):

If you require *at-most-once* delivery, use [Receive-and-Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#receiveanddelete) mode of Azure Service Bus. With that mode, the message is removed from the service when is provided to the client. But be aware that in case of a failure to process the message, the message will be gone.